# `is_trivially_destructible` does not work with inherited class

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


    class NoConstructOperation
    {
    protected:
        NoConstructOperation() = default;
        virtual ~NoConstructOperation() = default;
    public:
        NoConstructOperation(const NoConstructOperation&) = delete;
        NoConstructOperation& operator =(NoConstructOperation&) = delete;
        NoConstructOperation(NoConstructOperation&&) = delete;
        NoConstructOperation& operator = (NoConstructOperation&&) = delete;
    };

class Myclass:public NoConstructOperation
{

};


int main() {
    static_assert(!std::is_trivially_destructible<Myclass>::value, "Compiler provided destructor is public: Please declare it private");
    return 0;
}
```

If I do not inherit `Myclass` with `NoConstructOperation` above code gives compilation error with static assert.
  But if I inherit `Myclass` with `NoConstructOperation` `is_trivially_destructible` check does not work, even though `Myclass` constructor is public. This code compiles , **what is the reason**?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're defining `NoConstructorOperation`'s destructor as `virtual`. Removing `virtual` will trigger the static assertion as intended: [wandbox example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0OkbkU99wXSxZGhc).

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_trivially_destructible/):

> A trivially destructible class is a class (defined with class, struct or union) that:
>
> - uses the implicitly defined destructor.
> - the destructor is not virtual.
> - its base class and non-static data members (if any) are themselves also trivially destructible types.

From standard draft [N4567](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf) $12.4:

> A destructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> (5.4) — the destructor is not virtual,
>
> (5.5) — all of the direct base classes of its class have trivial destructors, and
>
> (5.6) — for all of the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such
>   class has a trivial destructor.

Comment: making a base-class destructor non-virtual can have different side effects though.

Comment: That's not the only problem

Comment: I want to enforce my client class aka Myclass should have copy/move constructors/assignment as deleted and ````constructor and destructor be in `private` scope. 
  Any better approach for this.

Comment: @gauravbharadwaj Why??? Just give the (base) classes a deleted copy and deleted assignment. But only, if these need that. Constructors (likely) and destructors (for sure) should stay public.

Comment: @DieterLücking Why should destructors stay public (for sure)?  If something is intended to be always smart pointer managed, public destructors are less than required.

Comment: @DieterLücking then anyone can instantiate NoConstructOperation class, which I guess does not look cool